# Husqvarna Viking 2000, on the off chance anyone knows the specs of the drive belt

Tags: sewing-machine, maintenance

I am looking to replace one of the drive belts, the smaller one with the square teeth, on my Husqvarna Viking 2000. I cannot find anywhere the size or type of belt used. Any help in finding a replacement or determining the specs of the missing belt would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to [sewingpartsonline.com](https://www.sewingpartsonline.com/cog-belt-short-9-1-2-viking-4111940-01.aspx) (not an endorsement) the Husqvarna Viking cog belt (short 9 1/2") part number is 4111940-01:

> Guaranteed to fit Husqvarna Viking Sewing Machine Models:
>    #1+, 100, 1020, 1030, 1040, 105, 1060, 120, 1200, 1250, 150, 180, 185, 190, **2000**, 2020, 3230, 3240, 4020, 4030, 5220, 5230, 5430, 6010, 6030, 610, 6170, 620, 6230, 6240, 6260, 6270, 630, 6360, 6370, 6430, 6440, 6460, 6470, 6570, 6690, 90, 95, Classica 100, Orchidea

[image]

This is my best guess based on my best effort at searching. Please verify your belt matches this description.